# Invert Slider and Play Button Position

Tags: manipulate, visualization

The following animation:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> 10], {i, 1, 10, 
  ControlType -> Animator}]
```

Gives:

[image]

How can I exchange `Slider` and Play Button Position, like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two controls, an `Animator` and a  `Slider` (or a `Manipulator`),  both tied to the same variable:

```
Manipulate[Plot[i*Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> 10], 
 Row[{Control[{i, 1, 10, Animator,  AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", 
   "StepRightButton", "PlayPauseButton", "FasterSlowerButtons", "DirectionButton"}}],
  Control[{{i, 1, ""}, 1, 10, Slider}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer ! This is great ! I just think that you forgot to put "ControlType ->" before Animator.

Comment: @james, my pleasure. You can have `ControlType -> Animator` or just `Animator`; both work.